# What's the best way to convert HTML/JS project to GWT

Tags: html, css, gwt

A designer company have made a prototype of a web application using HTML/CSS/JS, with forms, menus, roll-over sub-menus ... Now I have to take this prototype and build GWT views using widgets.

My question is : Do I have to start from scratch and build every view with UIBuinders and integrate the CSS files or there is an easy way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion - don't generate HTML. This basically means not using GWT widgets (or only using widgets that provide `.wrap(element)` method.

I'm taking this approach with my projects and works very well. I put all HTML in one big file and then hide (`display: none`) all divs. Then I use gwtQuery to identify, copy and show relevant parts. qwtQuery is also used inject behavior (event handlers).

Comment: I taught that hole the point of using GWT is to avoid using JavaScript. But if I have to stick with full GWT with UIBinder...I think I wouldn't have a choice to rebuild the views

Comment: Javascript? No. GwtQuery is a port of jQuery written in Java/gwt.

Comment: I checked out the GwtQuery, the code it's kind of JQuery  wrapped in  Java, but I agree that you can do stuff that can't be done with widgets alone in GWT. In your projects, I am curious to know how did you use MVP and GQuery together ?

Comment: GwtQuery is a port (rewrite in java) of jQuery, not a wrapper. In my Views I manipulate html with gwtQuery instead of instantiating GWT widgets. However there is a bit of mismatch because MVP expect you'll pass (eventually) a Widget to activityManager.setDisplay().